# Prevent resizing of a view controller presented as a sheet?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Is there a way to prevent a view from being resized if the view controller is presented as a sheet using the method `presentViewControllerAsSheet` or using a segue of style "sheet"?

Note that modal/show segues can be implanted to a window controller which can be set as non resizable from the storyboard itself. Segues of type popover are non-resizable by default.

[image: resizable sheet]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you tried setting your sheet view controller's `-preferredContentSize`? Failing that, what about adding width and height `NSLayoutConstraint`s to the view controller's view on `-viewDidLoad`?

Comment: PreferredContentSize fixes this issue.

Comment: was searching all over until I found this post, the preferedContentSize works magic... in Swift under viewDidLoad: self.preferredContentSize = NSSize(width: 500.0, height: 700.0)

Comment: No way to do this in Interface Builder?

Comment: Not that I've noticed recently.

Comment: Here's a slight modification that will pick up the size automatically from IB/constraints: `preferredContentSize = view.frame.size`

Comment: I wouldn't rely on that. The timing of the layout cycles isn't guaranteed since Auto Layout, Core Animation, and possibly more things touch the view's frame at different times. You should *never* tie a layout constraint to anything's frame for this reason. Thst it happens to work now is lucky but that could change at any time.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me. The sheet is no longer resizable:

```
override func viewWillLayout() {
    preferredContentSize = view.frame.size
}
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the other solutions worked for me, so I ended up using an `NSWindow` as the sheet controller (rather than a `NSViewController` on its own).

Declare an `NSWindowController` object in your header file:

```
NSWindowController *detailWindow;
```

To open the window in the form of a sheet, use the following code:

```
NSStoryboard *storyFile = [NSStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
detailWindow = [storyFile instantiateInitialController];
[self.view.window beginSheet:detailWindow.window completionHandler:nil];
```

To close the window:

```
[self.view.window endSheet:detailWindow.window];
```

In order to stop the window sheet from being resized, simply set the `NSWindow` minimum/maximum size in interface builder:

[image]

That's it, super easy! (Don't forget to set the window controller, as the initial controller).

Answer (score 0):

the above methods did not work for me .
`self.view.autoresizesSubviews = NO;` 
this line in viewcontroller should do the trick if the above methods didnt work